# Access additional information in an observable - Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am generating a user list using the below code but I would also like to access another list `userStatus` which shows the status for each user. How do I combine both?

```
  /**
   * @param  {string} id
   */
  setGuests(id: string): object {
    this.guestsRef = this.db.list<any>(`attending/${id}`, ref => ref.orderByChild('first_name'))
    return this.guests = this.guestsRef.snapshotChanges()
      .map(changes => {
        let guests = changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
        return guests
      })
  }

userStatus 
  - userKey
  -- status: offline or online
```

I tried using a method to get the user's status but it freezes.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let guest of guests | async">
    <ion-item class="guest-list"
      *ngIf="checkDisabled(guest) && guest.first_name">

      <ion-thumbnail (click)="userModal(guest)" item-start>
        <img [src]="thumb(guest)">
      </ion-thumbnail>

      <p (click)="userModal(guest)">
        {{(guest)?.first_name}} {{(guest)?.last_name}}
        <ion-icon *ngIf="setStatus(guest?.key)" style="color: lightgreen; float: right;"
          name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon>
      </p>

    </ion-item>
  </ng-container>


  /**
   * @param  {} uid
   */
  setStatus(uid) {
    this.statusSub = this.db.object(`userStatus/${uid}/status`)
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(status => {
        if (status === 'online') {
          return true
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: That is called a client-side join. I haven't done them in AngularFire2 in a while, but it looks like this contains many good places to start: https://www.google.com/search?q=angularfire2+join+query

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look.